# How to stop shuffle playing audiobooks and other non-music?

Tags: music-player, audiobooks

`.nomedia` hides it from the player, but I still want to be able to play it. Just not with the rest of my music.

Answer (score 1):

Continue to use the .nomedia file in your  audio book directory and use a separate audio book player like [MortPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.audiobookplayer) for listening to non-music audio files like audio books.

Personally I use MortPlayer for audio books, [BeyondPod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.beyondpod) for podcasts and the built in music player for music and things go pretty smoothly.  I don't have audio books messing up my playlists and BeyondPod and MortPlayer have features better suited to listening to audio books and podcasts, respectively.